# Tables not showing in document

Tags: tables

I'm attempting to create a cheatsheet for my upcoming Mathematics exam using LaTeX, and the tables aren't rendering. The error is an overfull hbox error.

The template I am using is:
https://github.com/tim-st/latex-cheatsheet

And the table I am trying to use is:

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}cccccc@{}}
\toprule
x        & 0        & 1            & 2       & 3         & 4          \\ \midrule
y        & c        & a+b+c        & 4a+2b+c & 9a+3b+c   & 16a+4b+c   \\
1st diff & \multicolumn{2}{c}{a+b} & 3a+b    & 5a+b      & 7a+b       \\
2nd diff & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2a}            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2a} \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I am clueless how to solve this :d

Comment: Welcome! `overfull hbox` are usually *warnings*, and not known to make tables disappear. Please post a complete minimal working example, which starts with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}`, can be compiled and shows the issue.

Comment: did you use begin{table}

Comment: Remove the `\end{table}`(and if you used it: `\begin{table}`). I assume you don't want your table to float in a cheatsheet and in addition, `multicol` does not support `table` environments inside of the `multicols` environment. To overcome the overfull box warning, either reduce the font size (`\scriptsize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1.25pt}`) in the table or reduce the number of columns to 3.

Comment: @leandriis Thank you so much, this worked great! I spent too long trying to fix this haha